# Ошибка при загрузке видео в ВК

Tags: python, vkontakte-api, вконтакте

Всех приветствую. Пытаюсь загрузить видео в ВК с помощью библиотеки vk_api, но получаю такую ошибку:

> vk_api.exceptions.ApiError: [27] Group authorization failed: method is
>   unavailable with group auth.

Можно ли вообще загрузить видео в сообщество?

Код:

```
import vk_api

token = "мой токен"

vk_session = vk_api.VkApi(token=token)

upload = vk_api.VkUpload(vk_session)
            #видео в папке с проектом
upload.video("video.mp4", name="test_video", group_id=мой ид группы)
```

Comment: Возможно что-то не так с правами доступа данного токена.

Comment: @Mark Minerov, хм, вроде в access token'e все возможные пункты выставил

Comment: Слышал что vk api заблокировали некоторые действия для ботов, ознакомся с этим списком.

Comment: С помощью ключа сообщества нельзя воспользоваться ни одним методом секции [`video`](https://vk.com/dev/video). Ошибка говорит сама за себя.